# How to mock a method whose class is decided on runtime?

Tags: python, mocking

Assume all of the following blocks are in different files. How do I mock the call to self.eggs.baz in C.foobar()

```
def foo(c):
    if c == 1:
        return A()
    elif c == 2:
        return B():


class A:
    def bar():
        pass

class B:
    def baz():
        pass

class C:
    def __init__():
        self.eggs = foo(2)

    def foobar():
        #How do I mock the line below?
        self.eggs.baz()
```

Comment: Why not mock out `foo`?

Comment: What is your purpose from mocking? Isn’t there an alternative?

Comment: The method I intend to mock is causing side-effects which I rather not have during testing.